# CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend ERROR spark

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I use Spark 2.1.1 and Scala 2.10 with Spark Standalone of two nodes.

I'd like to execute a Spark code that reads a dataset from a MySQL table and writes it to a Cassandra table.

**CODE :**

```
object RdmsToCassandra extends Serializable {

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.22.231")
  val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.22.231:7077", "MigrateMySQLToCassandra", conf)
  val mysqlJdbcString: String = s"jdbc:mysql://192.168.22.238/customer_events?user=root&password=qweqwe"
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance

    CassandraConnector(conf).withSessionDo { session =>
    session.execute("CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS test WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 2 }")
    session.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.store(  store_name text PRIMARY KEY, location text, store_type text)" )
  }
  val highestId: Long = 2
  val startingId: Long = 0
  val numberOfPartitions = 1;

val customerEvents = new JdbcRDD(sc, () => { DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlJdbcString)},
    "select * from store limit ?, ?",startingId,  highestId,  numberOfPartitions,
     (r: ResultSet) => {
        (r.getString("store_name"),
        r.getString("location"),
        r.getString("store_type")
        )
    }
    )


  customerEvents.saveToCassandra("test", "store1",
      SomeColumns("store_name"))

}

}
```

I submit the application using the command:

```
spark-submit --master spark://192.168.22.231:6066 \
  --class "RdmsToCassandra" \
  rdbmstocassandra_2.10-1.0.jar
```

During execution I am getting following error _

> Using Spark's default log4j profile:
>   org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties 17/05/26 15:45:51 INFO
>   CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name:
>   10619@totalprices-db-server-02 17/05/26 15:45:51 INFO SignalUtils:
>   Registered signal handler for TERM 17/05/26 15:45:51 INFO SignalUtils:
>   Registered signal handler for HUP 17/05/26 15:45:51 INFO SignalUtils:
>   Registered signal handler for INT 17/05/26 15:45:51 WARN
>   NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
>   platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 17/05/26
>   15:45:51 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root 17/05/26
>   15:45:51 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root 17/05/26
>   15:45:51 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:  17/05/26
>   15:45:51 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
>   17/05/26 15:45:51 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager:
>   authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view
>   permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users 
>   with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions:
>   Set() 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully
>   created connection to /192.168.22.231:36249 after 60 ms (0 ms spent in
>   bootstraps) 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls
>   to: root 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls
>   to: root 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls
>   groups to:  17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify
>   acls groups to:  17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO SecurityManager:
>   SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users 
>   with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set();
>   users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify
>   permissions: Set() 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO TransportClientFactory:
>   Successfully created connection to /192.168.22.231:36249 after 1 ms (0
>   ms spent in bootstraps) 17/05/26 15:45:52 WARN Utils: Your hostname,
>   totalprices-db-server-02 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1;
>   using 221.243.36.126 instead (on interface em1) 17/05/26 15:45:52 WARN
>   Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
>   17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at
>   /tmp/spark-73513e64-f52c-48c5-bf9e-bbc45caec12d/executor-fd21cdc3-673e-4b9e-9bd2-6cef1e3da140/blockmgr-157ab1c4-ca1e-481b-9357-b5855ee6beef
>   17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity
>   2004.6 MB 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver:
>   spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@192.168.22.231:36249 17/05/26 15:45:52
>   INFO WorkerWatcher: Connecting to worker
>   spark://Worker@221.243.36.126:40561 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO
>   TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to
>   /221.243.36.126:40561 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps) 17/05/26
>   15:45:52 INFO WorkerWatcher: Successfully connected to
>   spark://Worker@221.243.36.126:40561 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO
>   CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
>   17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID 0 on host
>   221.243.36.126 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on
>   port 43114. 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server
>   created on 221.243.36.126:43114 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO BlockManager:
>   Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block
>   replication policy 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster:
>   Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 221.243.36.126, 43114,
>   None) 17/05/26 15:45:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered
>   BlockManager BlockManagerId(0, 221.243.36.126, 43114, None) 17/05/26
>   15:45:52 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager:
>   BlockManagerId(0, 221.243.36.126, 43114, None) 17/05/26 15:46:00 INFO
>   CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown 17/05/26
>   15:46:00 **ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM**
>   tdown

Can anybody suggest what could be the problem here.

Comment: Can you use https://pastebin.com to paste the **entire** logs from the spark-submit?

Comment: Do you perhaps use Scala 2.10 to compile your Spark application and Spark 2.1.1 (with Scala 2.11 by default)? Can you make sure you're on the same level of Scala versions in the app and the env?

Comment: I am using Scala 2.12.2

Comment: @JacekLaskowski sorry for the previous comment btw I am using Scala 2.10, I will check with Scala 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is kind of old but maybe helpful for somebody else stopping by:

I faced a similar issue where the investigation of the NodeManager-Logs lead me to the root cause.
You can access them via the Web-interface

```
nodeManagerAdress:PORT/logs
```

The **PORT** is specified in the *yarn-site.xml* under *yarn.nodemanager.webapp.address*. (default: **8042**)

**My Investigation-Workflow:**

1. Collect logs (yarn logs ... command)
2. Identify node and container (in these logs) emitting the *error*
3. Search the NodeManager-logs by Timestamp of the *error* for a root cause

Btw: you can access the aggregated collection (xml) of all configurations affecting a node at the same port with:

```
 nodeManagerAdress:PORT/conf
```